# how let intel 82599 controller dispatch(proxy) lldp packet to underlying VFs ? can it be achieved by modifying ixgbe driver code?

Tags: virtualization

Our case is app inside KVM need LLDP packet from VF. So we'd like to know how to enable this. Can this be achieved by hack ixgbe driver code or just do some proper settings for the driver ?

Comment: While I am not 100% sure, I think VF must be a trusted VF to allow passing LLDP traffic.

Comment: so any trusted VF will receive the same lldp packet received from PF ?

Comment: Likely yes. Try it out.

Comment: hi Tomek, seems i can not turn on trust for vf :

       * #ip link set dev eth4 vf 2 trust on
         * Command line is not complete. Try option "help"

the only option avaliable is spoofchk...

Comment: hi Tomek, after upgrade iproute2，i set vf trust on and spoof checking off, but no luck... still lldp can not captured inside kvm.